# Terminal velocity of accelerated rain drop

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, explosions

Lets say an airplane flies above a cloud and drops a bomb that detonates inside the cloud.
The detonation velocity is 6900m/s.

Will a raindrop surrounding the detonation site be accelerated to detonation speed? 
Does the drop stop accelerating as soon as it reaches its (8m/s) terminal velocity? 

How far will a raindrop travel until the friction force will have decelerated it to terminal velocity ?

Answer (score 0):

While calculating terminal velocity, we consider force of gravity and friction. But in your case there's additional force on the water drop exerted by detonating particles. In this case the terminal velocity would be different than mere a free fall. Please see the derivation of calculating terminal speed in any textbook and modify the same as per your question.